# Using value of a JSON object within the same object and concatenation of JSON value strings

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object named myJSONobject with three name value pairs given below. I need to make a new JSON element named `place` by concatenating a string (example: Oceania) with two other strings which are values from the same JSON object. So is the following valid? Specially see the value of `place`. Is my way of writing the value correct?

```
{
    "country": "AUS",
    "state":"VIC",
    "place": ""Oceania" + myJSONobject['country'] + myJSONobject['state']",
}
```

Comment: thats javascript

Comment: Thanks. But what if I need to exchange some data with JSON and need to achieve this.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(myJSONobject)` - that will have the correct values.